# EOS 7 install failure

Tags: system-installation

Sooooo,

I've got a Dell Inspiron 7437 that runs EOS v6.1 just peachy.

Doing a complete disk wipe and the attempting to install EOS 7, it tells me the install failed "possibly" due to a hardware failure. Not the most helpful error statement in the world.

I've been through this numerous times, and redownloaded the ISO and made boot USB's using both Linux and Windows with the same result.

thoughts

Comment: Works just fine in demo mode.

Comment: More info... sure would be nice if we could use the enter keep here......

Comment: INFO: Extracting /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs

Comment: DEBUG: "unsquashfs" "-f" "-d" "/tmp/distinst.4Xc09V1KFW00" "/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs"

Comment: ERROR: extracting error: archive extraction failed with atatus: exit status 1

Comment: getting exactly the same error please lmk if you worked it out!

Comment: Nope. Sorry never got resolution.

Comment: Actually I worked it out - you need to manually format the partitions and tell the installer which one to use as boot, swap, etc

Took about 10 installs and tons of experimenting but eventually got it working (typing this from eos haha)

Comment: Wow. Good on you. I gave up and installed Win10 32 bit on the machine to support a very specific piece of software.